# Safe way to delete pdf files while showing on the screen

Tags: java, pdf

I have a method which calls another method that opens already saved a pdf file to screen by swingutilities thread mechanism. While it opens the pdf file from the given client path, the rest of method deals with cleaning all pdf files from the folder.

My problem is that if I call this method numerous times to open up several pdf files at the same time, what is the best way to clean up the path that contains all pdf files in terms of memory management.

My code snippet looks like:

```
public void fileSaveFinished(String filePath){
         openPDFReport(filePath); //display pdf to screen
         cleanFolderContent(folderPath, filePath); // It cleans folder contents except given filePath}

public void opendPDFReport(String filePath){


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        PDFFileLauncher.open(filePath);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here your question is related to shared resources. You are to read PDF and delete the same. So you must go for method pooling and use the wait and notify method to manage the working. Wait till file read operation not completed and notify the same to delete the file. For more details of wait and notify please some good tutorials. They will surely solve your problem.